# Sending Google Calendar Invites via Salesforce List Emails

Tags: einstein, calendar

Is it possible to send Google calendar invites through Salesforce where the Google calendar widget pops up just like how when you schedule it through Gmail with the invite it pops up?

[image: Example of what I'm trying to get]

I've tried integrating G Suite to Einstein, making it an .ics (but only really works for Outlook and not Google) and I'm at a loss.

Thanks

Comment: Custom email template that uses [GMail-friendly markup](https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/getting-started#your_first_markup) + automation to inject content into said template.